# What is the E-mail Attachment limitation in android?

Tags: android

I wanted to know what is the maximum size of the file that we can attach with e-mail in android? Or is the attachment limit completely dependent on E-mail that we have configured ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but based on work I've doen with Bitmaps you won't be able to access information from within your application running from rom if it exceeds 4mb.

If however the e-mail is saved to the SD card or filestore in general, I believe you will not reach a limit.

This is more an educated guess  :)

Answer (score 0):

if it's through gmail it's 20 or 25MB

if it's through an imap or pop3 server (ie: your own mail server) it's just 2MB.

I have no idea why there is such a low limit and no one seems to have an answer other than the obvious 'google wants to force people to use gmail'

Answer (score 0):

Not true. 
The Gmail limit is around 3MB. It is 100% useless.